# Timing issue of passing JSON object between functions creates error

Tags: jquery, ajax, json, response, timing

My function below makes and AJAX call and since it is an invalid JSON object returned I have to manually parse the results into a valid JSON object (which works).  The problem is when I am passing the JSON object back to the original calling function the object doesn't get passed back correctly.

If I only put the third alert in it will say 'invalid' for the object.  However if I put all three alerts in, only alert 2 will say invalid (1 and 3 will show object).  This makes believe it might be some type of timing issue passing the object between these variables.  Any recommendations on how to resolve this, as I obviously cannot put alerts in my final code.

```
    function loadDocuments(){
       var myDocuments = getDocs();
       alert('third response ' + myDocuments);
    }

    function getDocs() {            
            var myURL = "someURL";
            var response;
            $.ajax({
                url: myURL,
                type: 'GET',
                dataType: 'json',
                 complete: function(docData) {
                   if(docData.status==200){
                       response = parseDocResults(docData.responseText);
                       alert('first response' + response);                                                   
                   }else{
                       response = "Documents failed to load";
                   }
                }
            });
            alert('second response' + response);
         return response;
    }
```

Comment: AJAX is asynchronous, your returning value logic here cannot works

Comment: But I am not triggering the callback until 'complete'

Comment: Is there anyway to achieve this?  (parse results and pass them back)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using AJAX the way you tried it means using it in a `synchronous` approach which blocks the browser until the transfer is finished. You can find an `async` configuration flag for the `$.ajax()` function which makes the AJAX work synchronous when set to `false` but I wouldn't recommend it (and it's deprecated too).

The `$.ajax()` function just sends an HTTP request towards the server. It does not wait for a reply it returns immediately and execution continues with what ever instructions were  after the ajax function call.

Sometime later the browser (JavaScript) receives an HTTP response from the server. Your ajax function call specified a `complete`/`success` callback which is used to handle the HTTP response. But since that callback was executed "sometime later" you have to shape your logic from within the callback, without relying on a return value.

Comment: Based on this answer, what I did was to put all my downstream logic directly in the response section of the AJAX call vs returning anything after the call.  this of course worked.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You could do it just like this:

```
var myDocuments;

getDocs(); //call getDocs() instead of loadDocuments() in your coding logic

function loadDocuments(response){
        myDocuments = response;
        alert(myDocuments);
    }

    function getDocs() {            
            var myURL = "someURL";
            var response;
            $.ajax({
                url: myURL,
                type: 'GET',
                dataType: 'json',
                 complete: function(docData) {
                   if(docData.status==200){
                       response = parseDocResults(docData.responseText);
                       alert('first response' + response);                                                   
                   }else{
                       response = "Documents failed to load";
                   }

                   loadDocuments(response);
                }
            });            
    }
```